# Encrypt/Decrypt using java javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec

Tags: java, cryptography, secret-key

I am new to security. I have to encrypt and decrypt using Java's javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec.

I am generating a KEY and IV in shell script. By calling the shell script from a Java class, I am getting the KEY and IV values as strings in my Java code.
I am setting the values in a POJO as strings.

Now can I use the KEY and IV to encrypt and decrypt any string?

Please find the example below.

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
int count= 0;
KeyIvPojo keyIv= new KeyIvPojo();

Process p;
try {
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("keyIv.sh -g");
    p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] lines= line.split(",");
        for (String str : lines) {
            if (count==0) {
                keyIv.setKey(str);
                System.out.println("Value of Key::::"+keyIv.getKey());
            } else if (count==1) {
                keyIv.setIv(str);
                System.out.println("Value of Iv::::"+keyIv.getIv());    
            }
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Class KeyIvPojo {
    String Key;
    String Iv;

    setters and getters...

}
```

Comment: Minor layout and grammar improvements.

Comment: Added tags, cleaned up code layout, minor grammar and layout improvements.

Comment: How does `count==1` ever become true?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot, at least not without leaking information. This is because encrypting multiple messages with the same key means that you need multiple IV's. You can make it work, but you cannot make it fully secure.

Java is perfectly capable of creating a key and IV, so I'm not sure what you are using the script for.

Keys and IV's are binary values, they should not be strings. Strings cannot be explicitly destroyed in Java (they're immutable), so using strings for keys is a bad idea, even if they have been hex or base 64 encoded.